# Invisible changes in my post?

Tags: support, editing

I am aware that I make mistakes and do not follow the conventions and know nothing about the codes used for formulae so it is good when somebody edits my post. But I am curious, in [this editing](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/37484) some real mistakes were corrected but also some words deleted and inserted as they were, at least in my browser (Firefox).

Is it possible that in other browsers some everyday characters are interpreted differently? For example, I see no difference in the spelling and settings for "telescope" and "the" in the first line.

As sometimes the spell checker does that too, I am wondering if my keyboard does something funny (it is also a greek keyboard) that others can see who do not have greek in their browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the diff in the default "rendered output" view, you see words like "telescope" and "the" are highlighted like they've been changed but you can't see the changes.

If you switch to the "markdown" view though, you can see what changed.  In both cases you used two spaces before the words:

```
a<space><space>telescope focusing<space><space>the
```

Multiple spaces in a row are not rendered so they look like one space in rendered output even though they are more than one space in markup.  So when your answer was edited and the extra spaces removed, no visible change was made but the diff engine still detected the change and highlighted it for you.  This is why it looks like no change was made but there are still words highlighted.

Comment: thank you    Brandon